# Asp.Net Core - How to create object-specific sub-routes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a model class Dispute with one-to-many relationships. 
I would navigate and perform CRUD operation on its related objects within a specific disputeId.
I would compose the url as follow:

```cs
Disputes/Details/(disputeId)/(related_objects)
```

where related_objects can be, for example, Persons, God, etc.
What kind of approach i can use?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. That *is* how you would do it. Though, technically it should just be `disputes/{disputeId}`.  "Details" is superfluous as a GET on an ID route is *supposed* to return details.

Comment: Each dispute has lists of related objects, i.e. persons, that I would manage through different tables. So if I navigate to `disputes/{disputeId}/persons` I would display the table of persons related to disputeId object.

Comment: And? What are you asking?

Comment: I don't know how can I realize the above url structure  and pass the id to retrieve the related objects

Answer (score 0):

You could use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing) to realize the route. You need to pass navigation properties as your relative_objects.Refer to my demo:

1.Model:

```
public class Dispute
{
    [Key]
    public int DisputeId { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
}
```

2.DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Dispute> Disputes{ get; set; }
public DbSet<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
```

3.Controller:

```
[Route("Disputes")]
public class DisputesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ProductsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    // GET: Disputes/Details/5/Persons
    [Route("Disputes/{disputeId}/{related_objects}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? disputeId, string related_objects)
    {
        if (disputeId== null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var dispute = await _context.Disputes.Include(related_objects)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DisputeId == disputeId);

       //other logic
    }
}
```